# How to prevent event propagation to the parent element? @input.stop doesn't work. (NuxtJS)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a text field built right into a vuetify expansion panel.

[image: SS]

After clicking the "rename box" icon

[image: Editable]

The issue is that every time I type a spacebar into the text box the expansion panel toggles. I have prevented the event propagation of a click by using click.stop="" attribute but I cant seem to prevent this space bar event from affecting the parent.

Attributes that I have tested are:

1. keydown.stop
2. keydown.prevent ('Cant type with this option')
3. keydown.self
4. keydown.capture
5. input.stop
6. change.stop

The following are the events emitted according to the vue plugin

[image]

Here is the code

```html
<v-expansion-panel
active
v-for="(item, i) in $store.state.data"
:key="i"
>
<v-expansion-panel-header>
  <div v-if="editorQ !== i">Q. {{ item.q }}</div>
  <v-text-field
    v-else
    label="Question"
    :value="newQuestion"
    @click.stop=""
    @change.stop="updateQ"
    @keydown.stop=""
  ></v-text-field>
  <template v-slot:actions>
    <v-btn
      v-if="editorQ === i"
      @click.stop="doneEditingQuestion(i)"
      depressed
      icon
      text
    >
      <v-icon> mdi-check </v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn
      class="upright"
      v-else
      @click.stop="editQuestion(i)"
      depressed
      icon
      text
    >
      <v-icon> mdi-rename-box </v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </template>
</v-expansion-panel-header>
<v-expansion-panel-content>
```

Comment: The event fires on `keydown` as opposed to `change` I believe, give `keydown` a go, more specifically, `keydown.space.stop`

Comment: tried it. I have added a list of attributes that I have tried too.

Comment: Tried `input.prevent.stop`? Is this behavior allowed by the vuetify API btw? I mean, maybe it's not the way that this should work.

Comment: doesnt work. Getting an error instead

Comment: Which error...?

Comment: TypeError: $event.stopPropagation is not a function. The above expression works with keydown.stop.prevent. However, I cant type anything anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was just trial and error for me, the following prevents the `active` toggle:

```
@click.stop
@keyup.prevent
```

when applied to the `v-text-field` within a `v-expansion-panel-header`.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/gswits/pen/OJpMXrK?editors=1111)

Comment: For real? Haha, that's why I do not use vuetify. I hope that the OP can update his title and make it easy to find back for any people looking for this issue.

Comment: @kissu I hear you there. Vuetify and I have a true love/hate relationship.